# Is history about Hindu kings or famous persons on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

There are many kings and famous poets who contributed their roles in nurturing Hinduism. So, shall we consider asking questions regarding the famous people as on-topic?

For example,

- Vikramaditya
- Prithviraj Chauhan
- Kalidas
- Tulsidas
- Chatrapathi Shivaji

I think we should consider having an [history](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) tag.

Comment: +1 for asking it.

Comment: I am damn sure, I got the -1 for saying to have an history tag. :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Vikramaditya

He apparently shows up in the Bhavishya Purana, so questions about his role in that text would be on-topic. Questions about his place in the historical record ought to be off-topic.

> Prithviraj Chauhan
>   Chatrapathi Shivaji

Definitely not. Other than *being* Hindus, they have nothing to do with Hinduism whatsoever. Questions about him go to History.SE.

> Kalidas

I can see questions about his religious literature *maybe* being on-topic, particularly in the context of a comparison with the scriptures (e.g. why does Kalidasa's *Recognition of Shakuntala* differ from the *Mahabharata* in aspect X). Questions about Kalidasa's non-religious literature and about Kalidasa himself should be off-topic.

> Tulsidas

Tulsidas's *Ramcharitmanas* is definitely on-topic. His other religious literature may also be (cf. what I wrote for Kalidas). Again, non-religious literature and questions about Tulsidas himself are probably off-topic.

---

Think about the implications of what you're saying. Should we just give carte blanche for *any* question about people who are Hindu? That broadens the scope of this site to an unmanageable degree.

Comment: +1,Completely agree.